# Flatten parent child relationship in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables in SQL Server: Household and People. Household represents a home and People represents the people living in the home:

**Household**

```
Id       Address        City        State          Zip
------------------------------------------------------
1        123 Main       Anytown     CA           90121
```

**People**

```
Id        HouseholdId       Name        Age
-------------------------------------------
1         1                 John         32
2         1                 Jane         29
```

I want to query the two tables and end up with a result set like below, but I'm not sure how best to approach this:

```
Id        Address        City        State        Zip        Person1Name        Person1Age        Person2Name     Person2Age
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1         123 Main       Anytown     CA           90121      John                       32        Jane                    29
```

Of course, "PersonXName and PersonXAge" should repeat based on how many people there are. How can I write a query that would accomplish this? Simplicity is preferred over performance as this is a one-off report I need to come up with.

Comment: Either PIVOT or a cross tab. Why do you store age? You should store birth date instead.

Comment: It's an arbitrary example. The real schema is different and there is no "Age" column. I'm looking more for a sample query based on simplistic data, I'll adapt it to my actual schema.

Comment: that's correct @SeanLange +1. age can be derived from DOB.

Comment: @user2989408 That's not true. You can do a dynamic pivot. I prefer the crosstab approach. They are faster performance wise and are much easier to understand. Here is a static approach. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/63681/ And here is the dynamic version http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Crosstab/65048/

Comment: @SeanLange By my previous comment, I meant it cannot be done using static SQL. Sure, you can do it by building dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is done using a dynamic cross tab. For reference: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Crosstab/65048/

```
CREATE TABLE HouseHold(
    ID      INT,
    Address VARCHAR(20),
    City    VARCHAR(20),
    State   CHAR(2),
    Zip     VARCHAR(10)
)
CREATE TABLE People(
    ID          INT,
    HouseHoldID INT,
    Name        VARCHAR(20),
    Age         INT
)
INSERT INTO HouseHold VALUES
(1, '123 Main', 'Anytown', 'CA', '90121');
INSERT INTO People VALUES
(1, 1, 'John', 32),
(2, 1, 'Jane', 29);

DECLARE @sql1 VARCHAR(4000) = ''
DECLARE @sql2 VARCHAR(4000) = ''
DECLARE @sql3 VARCHAR(4000) = ''

SELECT @sql1 =
'SELECT
     ID
    ,Address
    ,City
    ,State
    ,Zip'
+ CHAR(10)

SELECT @sql2 = @sql2 +
'   ,MAX(CASE WHEN RN = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), RN) + ' THEN Name END) AS [Person' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), RN) + 'Name]
    ,MAX(CASE WHEN RN = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), RN) + ' THEN Age END) AS [Person' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), RN) + 'Age]
'
FROM(
    SELECT DISTINCT RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY p.HouseHoldID ORDER BY p.ID)
    FROM People p   
)t

SELECT @sql3 =
'FROM(
    SELECT
        h.*
        ,p.Name
        ,p.Age
        ,RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY h.ID ORDER BY p.ID)
    FROM Household h
    INNER JOIN People p ON p.HouseHoldId = h.ID
)t
GROUP BY ID, Address, City, State, Zip
ORDER BY ID'

PRINT(@sql1 + @sql2 + @sql3)
EXEC (@sql1 + @sql2 + @sql3)

DROP TABLE HouseHold
DROP TABLE People
```

**RESULT**

```
ID          Address              City                 State Zip        Person1Name          Person1Age  Person2Name          Person2Age
----------- -------------------- -------------------- ----- ---------- -------------------- ----------- -------------------- -----------
1           123 Main             Anytown              CA    90121      John                 32          Jane                 29
```

Answer (score 1):

This is adapted from a script I use with a similar requirement. Probably don't want to use if the People table has a million rows, but works well enough for my use case with about 20000 rows:

```
DECLARE @id int, @householdid int, @name varchar(50), @age int, @currentid   int, @peoplecount int;
DECLARE @colsql nvarchar(1000), @datasql nvarchar(1000), @RunSql nvarchar(1000);

CREATE TABLE #ReturnTable (HouseholdId int, Address varchar(50))

INSERT #ReturnTable
SELECT Id, Address
FROM Household;

-- these are split into two dynamic queries
-- so that columns exist when we try the insert
SET @colsql = 'IF (SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM TempDB.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
  WHERE COLUMN_NAME = ''Person{Number}Name'' 
    AND TABLE_NAME LIKE ''#ReturnTable'') = 0
BEGIN
  ALTER TABLE #ReturnTable
  ADD Person{Number}Name VARCHAR(50)
END

IF (SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM TempDB.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
  WHERE COLUMN_NAME = ''Person{Number}Age'' 
    AND TABLE_NAME LIKE ''#ReturnTable'') = 0
BEGIN
  ALTER TABLE #ReturnTable
  ADD Person{Number}Age INT
END'

set @datasql =
'UPDATE #ReturnTable
SET Person{Number}Name = @name,
  Person{Number}Age = @age
WHERE HouseholdId = @householdid'

DECLARE PeopleCursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT p.Id, p.HouseholdId, p.Name, p.Age
FROM People p
ORDER BY p.HouseholdId, p.Age

OPEN PeopleCursor;

FETCH NEXT FROM PeopleCursor
INTO @id, @householdid, @name, @age

SET @currentid = @id

SET @peoplecount = 1;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    IF @currentid <> @id
    BEGIN
       SET @peoplecount = 1
       SET @currentid = @id
    END
    ELSE SET @peoplecount = @peoplecount + 1;

    SET @RunSql = REPLACE(@colsql, '{Number}', CAST(@peoplecount AS VARCHAR(3)));

    EXEC dbo.sp_ExecuteSql @RunSql

    SET @RunSql = REPLACE(@datasql, '{Number}', CAST(@peoplecount AS VARCHAR(3)));

    EXEC dbo.sp_ExecuteSql @RunSql, N'@householdid int, @name varchar(50), @age int', @householdid = @householdid, @name = @name, @age = @age;

    FETCH NEXT FROM PeopleCursor
    INTO @id, @householdid, @name, @age
END

CLOSE PeopleCursor
DEALLOCATE PeopleCursor

SELECT *
FROM #ReturnTable

drop table #ReturnTable
```

Answer (score 0):

Few changes are required, If you guys help me to solve this, it would be great...

```
 DECLARE @col1 nvarchar(max) = '', @col2 nvarchar(max) = ''
 declare @colname nvarchar(max),@query nvarchar(max), @cols nvarchar(max)=''

 DECLARE openall CURSOR for
 SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY NAME) rowno FROM People 

    OPEN openall
  fetch next from openall into @colname

while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    begin

        set @col1 += 'Person'+ @colname +'Name,'
        set @col2 += 'Person'+ @colname+'Age,'

        fetch next from openall into @colname
     end     

  set @col1 = LEFT(@col1,LEN(@col1)-1)
  set @col2 = LEFT(@col2,LEN(@col2)-1)

 set @query = 'SELECT ID, Address, City, State, Zip, ' + @col1 + ', ' + @col2 + ' 
       FROM ( 
        SELECT h.ID, Address, City, State, Zip,p.name,p.age from Household h 
         inner join people p on h.id = p.householdid
           ) x
        pivot
       (
      sum(age) for
      name in (' + @col1 + ', ' + @col2 + ')
      ) p '

     execute(@query)
     close openall
     deallocate openall
```

Answer (score 0):

This "flattening" operation is known as multicolumn dynamic pivot. It's dynamic because pivot column values are not known at design time, and it's multicolum because you have "age" and "name" pivot column values.

To do multicolumn dynamic pivot in SQL, you need to use dynamic sql and resort to case expressions. SQL Pivot operator doesn't work with multicolumn pivot. This is convoluted to implement.

I don't think SQL is the best language to perform multicolumn dynamic pivot. I think it is better done at client side.

The following c# method returns a data table containing the resultset you are asking for:

```
public DataTable GetPivotedPeople()
{
    using (var ds = new MyDataService())
    {
        return ds.PersonRepository
            .Query("Household")
            .OrderBy(PersonFields.HouseHoldId, PersonFields.Address, PersonFields.City, PersonFields.State, PersonFields.Zip)
            .Pivot(
                new PivotTransform
                {
                    PivotColumnName = PersonFields.PersonId,
                    ValueColumnName = PersonFields.Name,
                    GetPivotedColumnName = (personId) => "Person" + personId.ToString() + "Name"
                },
                new PivotTransform
                {
                    PivotColumnName = PersonFields.PersonId,
                    ValueColumnName = PersonFields.Age,
                    GetPivotedColumnName = (personId) => "Person" + personId.ToString() + "Age"
                }
            );
    }
}
```

This is the content of the returned data table:

```
+-------------+----------+---------+-------+-------+-------------+-------------+------------+------------+
| HouseHoldId | Address  |   Ciy   | State |  Zip  | Person1Name | Person2Name | Person1Age | Person2Age |
+-------------+----------+---------+-------+-------+-------------+-------------+------------+------------+
|           1 | 123 Main | Anytown | CA    | 90121 | John        | Jane        |         32 |         29 |
+-------------+----------+---------+-------+-------+-------------+-------------+------------+------------+
```

It uses [EntityLite](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/753796/i-nercya-EntityLite-A-Lightweight-Database-First-M), a micro ORM that I have developed. It queries Person_HouseHold view and rotates the rows at client side. Here you have the sql script:

```
CREATE DATABASE DynamicPivot
GO
USE DynamicPivot
GO
CREATE TABLE Households
(
    HouseholdId int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    [Address] nvarchar(128) NOT NULL,
    City nvarchar(128) NOT NULL,
    [State] nvarchar(128) NOT NULL,
    Zip nvarchar(128) NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO Households ([Address], City, [State], Zip) 
VALUES (N'123 Main', N'Anytown', N'CA', N'90121');
GO

CREATE TABLE People
(
    PersonId int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    HouseHoldId int NOT NULL CONSTRAINT FK_People_Households REFERENCES HouseHolds(HouseholdId),
    Name nvarchar(128) NOT NULL,
    Age int NOT NULL

);
INSERT INTO People(HouseHoldId, Name, Age) VALUES
(1, N'John', 32), (1, 'Jane', 29)

GO

CREATE VIEW Person_Household
AS
    SELECT 
        P.PersonId, P.HouseHoldId, P.Name, P.Age,
        H.[Address], H.City, H.[State], H.Zip
    FROM
        dbo.People P INNER JOIN dbo.Households H
            ON P.HouseHoldId = H.HouseholdId
```

I wrote [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/796651/Client-Side-Multi-Column-Dynamic-Pivot) on CodeProject. It explains you how to do pivot using sql and how to perform Pivot at client side using EntityLite or using raw ADO.NET. So to do pivot at client side you don't need to use EntityLite.

Answer (score -1):

Considering this is a one off you could consider this:

get the highest number of people living in the same house (select count)

join the people table to the Household table for each person.

```
SELECT * 
FROM Household 
LEFT JOIN People p1 
ON p1.HouseHoldId = Household.Id
LEFT JOIN People p2 
ON p2.HouseHoldId = Household.Id
```

Dpending on the indexes, optimalization settings and lots of other conditions this might even be a very performant solution.

Comment: Your query will flatten into four rows, all combinations of the two people rows, which is not the goal of the question. Your query produces the following: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/81cf7