# PIVOT in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, pivot

```html
TableA
------
UserID | UserName | Password
----------------------------
1        Test1      Pass
2        Test2      Pass
3        Test3      Pass


TableB
------
UserDetailID | UserID | FieldName | FieldValue
----------------------------------------------
1              1        Address1    #24, 2nd Main
2              1        Address2    Near to abc
3              1        City        Chennai
4              1        State       Tamilnadu
5              2        Address1    #45, 3rd Main
6              2        Address2    Near to XYZ
7              2        City        Bangalore
8              2        State       Karnataka

I need a pivot query which can convert this two table as below

UserID | UserName | Password | Address1      | Address2    | City   | State
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
1        Test1      Pass       #24, 2nd Main   Near to ABC   Chennai  Tamilnadu
2        Test2      Pass       #45, 3rd Main   Near to XYZ   Bangalore Karnataka

How i can achieve this?
```

Comment: Are the `FieldName`s fixed?

Comment: Fields are dynamic in TableB, It may also include Address3 and Address4

Comment: You can do this using dynamic crosstab. Check my answer [**here**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28469673/2203084).

Comment: @wewesthemenace even though we provided examples if this newbie unable to get the requirement done what should he do ??

Comment: @lak have you got your answer by the above provided link or still you need assistance

Comment: @mohan111 - Even though he/she is newbie he/she should put some effort this is a very basic question!!. There are thousands of answers present in internet for such questions

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15931607/convert-rows-to-columns-using-pivot-in-sql-server http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15745042/efficiently-convert-rows-to-columns-in-sql-server/15745076#15745076 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404348/sql-server-dynamic-pivot-query/10404455#10404455

Comment: yeah @Fireblade i agree with you mate

Comment: thanks everyone, i got the answer, thanks for the reference links